# Using regex to replace all hyphens in a json document but only there the same line contains a specific string

Tags: json, regex, visual-studio-code

I have a JSON file in VSCode.

I want to replace all hyphens in the document with underscores but only where the same line contains the text: `"product":`

For example:

```json
{
    "product": "replace-my-hyphens",
    "label": "do-not-replace-my-hyphens"
}
```

Comment: How are you reading the file? Because *"where the same line contains"* indicates to me that it is plain text. Why not parse the JSON file and loop over the object. This way you can more easily check for the key `product` and replace its value when needed.

Comment: @Reyno I am using vscode find and replace feature, not reading the file with code.

Comment: What @Reyno said is supremely important.  the JSON representation of any character object may be escaped and represented with Unicode escape sequences instead of literal text.  Actually parsing the JSON, then transforming its values, then reencoding as JSON is the only way to go for robust programmatic solutions.  I realize you're **just using your vscode editor**, and so this question is falsely tagged JavaScript.  And I'm going to remove that tag.

Comment: You could [write an extension for visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) that parses the JSON, performs your constrained replacements and then re-encodes the JSON.  If you want to solve the problem for your particular document (which may be a subset of JSON) then you should probably remove the JSON tag as well and just make it a search and replace problem defined by quoted strings with no escapes on the same line - not JSON.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please reopen because it can be done with find-replace in VSC

Comment: what to do: (1) select `"product":` (2) menu Selection > Select All Occurrences (3) Select till end of line: `Shift+End` (4) `Ctrl+F` (5) Select button `Find in selection` (3 lines) (6) Fill in `-` and `_` (7) Click button `Replace All` (8) `Esc` leave multi cursor mode

Answer (score 0):

what to do:

1. select `"product":`
2. menu **Selection** > **Select All Occurrences** (`Ctrl+Shift+L`)
3. Select till end of line: `Shift+End`
4. Open find/replace dialog: `Ctrl+F`
5. Select button **Find in selection** (3 lines)
6. Fill in (find) `-` and (replace) `_`
7. Click button **Replace All**
8. `Esc` leave multi cursor mode

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple find and replace:

Find: `(?<="product":.*?)-`
Replace: `_`

As you can see, any `-` will be matched that is preceded by `"product":` and some number of characters (except line terminators).

See [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/H0LUO3/1).

This works in a find within one file (i.e., using the Find Widget) but will not work in a Search across multiple files because of the non-fixed length lookbehind.